# Choppy Video Playback in 13.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, video

I've had a tremendous amount of trouble with my Nvidia drivers and have finally settled on a version that seems to be working acceptably. Kind of. When I view a video of any kind, irrelevant of quality, I get awfully choppy, pixelated video. I'm aware this is definitely more graphics issues and I'm edging closer to the final straw.

My question is not only can someone help me to fix these issues, but I'd like to know if there's a more recommended graphics card out there that won't have any problems. Are ATI cards less susceptible to these kind of problems? Am I best sacrificing performance and just running the onboard Intel?

I'm running a Packard Bell iXtreme with the following specs:

- Memory: 4GB
- Processor: i3-2100 @ 3.10 Ghz x4
- Graphics: GeForce GT 610/PCIe/SSE2 (with onboard Intel HD3000 that is disabled and 310 driver with xorg edgers.
- Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check your compiz-config and your nvidia-settings if you have V-Sync enabled?

I am running the 310 driver for ubuntu, but not with compiz. As I do not think it's performance with vsync is good enough. At work I am using a intel card with compiz, and it's a whole other deal, - works fluently. In my experience mutter or kwin does a better job with the vsync'ing in nvidia cards. Maybe someone else has a different experience, but I have had this problem both with my old 8800GT card and my current GTX 570.

There is a newer driver on the nvidia site 319.something. that you can try. But you will have to do a manual install.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've updated to the 319 driver and things have improved. I've noticed a slight choppiness in high definition video still but things are a lot more bearable. For other people in this situation, I recommend upping the profile in Nvidia-settings to 'Prefer Maximum Performance'. This can get help quite a bit.